# How to put text over an imagebutton not via xml

Tags: android, eclipse, text, overlay, imagebutton

I'm currently developing an android app with eclipse. Basicaly, I need to put the text over an imagebutton. There are some conditional statements in order to put text over that imagebutton, that's why I can't set the text in xml

This is how I set the imagebutton in xml:

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/question1"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"/>
```

This is how I set the image source and text of the button:

```
buttonQuestion1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.question1);
TextView listContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question1);
String question1 = getQuestion.get(0);

buttonQuestion1.setImageResource(R.drawable.button);
listContent.setText(question1);
```

The code to set the image source works fine. I use TextView and setText in order to put text over the imagebutton but when I try to run it, the app crashes. Anyone know how to set text over an imagebutton in a right way?

Comment: Take a Textview instead of ImageButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
TextView listContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question1);
```

gives error because `R.id.question1` is not a `TextView`, it's an `ImageButton`.

You can use normal `<Button/>` instead for layout

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/question1"
android:layout_width="150dip"
android:layout_height="50dip"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"/>
```

When you want to set the text and image resource, you can call

```
buttonQuestion1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
buttonQuestion1.setText(question1);
```

Comment: Button don't have ImageResource property, it have background resouce.. ImageResource is different from Background resource, ImageResource is dealing with foreground.